# probability of coin toss given the probability of heads is 2/3

Tags: probability

The probability of heads is set to 2/3. What is the conditional probability of getting heads in first toss and tails in second toss?

I'm looking at $P(A\mid B)=P(A\cap B)\,/\,P(B)$

I assume the two events is independent which mean $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B) \iff P(A\mid B)=P(A)$

$P(A)=1/4$ since there is one match out of the possible outcomes: $\{HH,TT,TH,HT\}$ which means $P(A\mid B)=1/4$

But logically speaking the answer should be $2/3$ (probability of heads) times $1/3$ (probability of tails) which equals $2/9$ ...

What am I missing here?

Comment: The second approach is correct. $P(A)=\frac{1}{4}$ is false for a biased coin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

The division of the count of favoured outcomes over the total count of outcomes *only* measures probability when *all outcomes have equal weight*.   With a *biased* coin this is clearly not the case.

Since heads are twice as 'heavy' as tails, when you include weighting your set is $$\big\{(\mathrm{HH}, 4), (\mathrm{HT}, 2), (\mathrm{TH}, 2), (\mathrm{TT},1)\big\}$$

Then $\mathsf P(A) = \frac{4+2}{4+2+2+1}=\tfrac 6 9 = \tfrac 2 3 \\ \mathsf P(B)= \frac{2+1}{4+2+2+1}=\tfrac 3 9 = \tfrac 1 3 \\ \mathsf P(A\mid B) = \frac{2}{2+1}=\tfrac 2 3 \\ \mathsf P(A\cap B)= \tfrac 2{4+2+2+1} = \tfrac 2 9$

As...expected.